# how to train image classification with small difference in low-level feature

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, computer-vision, accuracy, embeddings

I would like to build the model that capable of doing classification for example 2 classes below :
[image: img]

I tried alexnet, resnet50, resnet18, vgg16 but seem they are failed to differentiate between this two classes. The overall images looks similar but only differ by low-level feature on the bottom left of image. I need suggestion, how to improve the prediction and to make model can recognize the low-level feature to differentiate the images ?

thank you